# jQuery: counting visible elements - efficiency/speed problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, children, visible

I have some code that works fine but it's become too slow:

HTML:

I have a container that contains about 50 `ul` elements. Each `ul` element has a `h4` heading followed by a series of `li` elements. The function hides the heading if no line elements are visible.

Javascript/jQuery:

```
            function show_or_hide_headings() {
                $('#container').children('ul').each(function (i) {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        $h4 = $this.children(':first');
                    if ($this.children('li:visible').length) {
                        $h4.show();
                    } else {
                        $h4.hide();
                    }
                }); 
            }
```

It was working quite acceptably until I changed the nature of the `li` elements. Each `li` is now a mini table comprising `<table><tr><td>icon</td><td>text</td></tr></table>`. It now takes 2 seconds to process, whereas it previously worked in less than half a second. (The table is there to stop the text wrapping under the icon.)

I confess I can't quite understand why adding the additional elements into each `li` should slow down the DOM processing so much because I've used the `.children` selector to only go one DOM layer deep.

I've also tried:

```
                $('#container').find('h4').each(function (i) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.siblings('li:visible').length) {
                       $this.show();
                    } else {
                       $this.hide();
                    }
                });
```

and `$('#container').children().children('h4')` for good measure.

What is notable, too, is that when there are many `li` elements visible, it is much slower than when few are visible. There are no more lines now, however, than when it worked quite quickly (i.e., before the table was put into each line).

Any advice greatly appreciated, but please don't request I post more code than I have :)

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post an exmample of the related markup, from what you've said, it has issues. A [UL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-ul-element.html#the-ul-element) can **only** have LI child elements, the H4 is being error-corrected so you don't have the structure you think you do. Also, the table to format the content of the LI is unnecessary, use CSS. Oh, and an H4 can't have LIs as child nodes, they must have a UL or OL parent.

Comment: How about nowrap instead of table? Also why not hide the parent h4 when you hide the children instead of the other way around?

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll check the markup and get back on this one.

Comment: @RobG I just rebuilt the markup using document fragments and no dodgy inner HTML but it's still slow so I don't think that's it. (At least I can feel righteous about my code now.) I've also made the structure such that each `h4` element is followed by the `ul` containing only `li` items. I'm not sure about the CSS-not-table solution, though. I want wrap, but only within its own column (so nowrap is not suitable, I think).

Comment: If you post an example of your markup and add a CSS tag someone will help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that determining if an element is visible or not is quite expensive. Consider instead adding and deleting a class to hide or show elements. Then you can select them directly based on the class, which will mostly be supported by a host *getElementsByClassName* or *querySelectorAll* method.

Comment: This is the foundation of the mess I'm in! I *am* hiding and showing things by various classes, but now I need to determine if anything is still showing :)  The other thing is that it wasn't that expensive until I put the table into the line. That's the real conundrum. I can remove the table and it works fine.

Comment: I've ticked the answer in recognition of the good advice here and in the comment above, although no one has really answered the question as I asked it :) I've taken the table out and reformatted the markup which works around the problem fine.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$('h4', '#container').css('display', 'none').filter(function() {
    return $(this).siblings('li:visible').length;
}).css('display', 'block');
```

but I agree with RobG, you'r markup is probably incorrect.