# CSS to stop text wrapping under image

Tags: css, css-float, word-wrap

I have the following markup:

```
<li id="CN2787">
  <img class="fav_star" src="images/fav.png">
  <span>Text, text and more text</span>
</li>
```

I want it so that if the text wraps, it doesn't go into the 'column' for the image. I know I can do it with a `table` (which I was doing) but this is not workable for [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406964/jquery-counting-visible-elements-efficiency-speed-problems).

I've tried the following without success:

```
li span {width: 100px; margin-left: 20px}
.fav_star {width: 20px}
```

I also tried `float: right`.

Thanks.

EDIT: I want it to look like this:

```
IMG   Text starts here and keeps going... and
      wrap starts here.
```

Not like this:

```
IMG   Text starts here and keeps going... and 
wrap starts in the space left for the image.
```

Comment: can you put your code into jsfiddle ?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit clearer about your intentions here. If you do not want text to wrap then you can simply use `white-space: nowrap;` in `li span {...}`, but I get the impression that you are trying to do something else

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Apologies - seemed clear to me :)  I want two columns in the line. The left 20px is for an image. The remainder is for text. If the text wraps, I want it to begin the second line of the wrap 20px in from the left (under where the initial text began).

Comment: @Nick thanks, the edit has cleared up and confusion I had :)

Comment: For passers-by, you don't need to deal with widths as the accepted answer suggests. It's much simpler: create what's called a **new formatting context**. See Joe Conlin's answer. For futher background, see mine.

Comment: @hqcasanova  For the record, Dan's answer was accepted 9 months before Joe posted his and 16 months before you yours. I'm not going to unaccept Dan's answer, although thanks for adding alternatives.

Comment: @Nick I didn't even know you could unaccept an answer. For the record, that was not my intention as I think I expressed it clearly with "For passers-by". Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: No worries, @hqcasanova.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> #### Since this question is gaining lots of views and this was the accepted answer, I felt the need to add the following disclaimer:
>
> This answer was specific to the OP's question (Which had the width set in the examples). While it works, it requires you to have a width on each of the elements, the image and the paragraph. Unless that is your requirement, I recommend using [Joe Conlin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15421257/535122) which is posted as another answer on this question.

The `span` element is an inline element, you can't change its width in CSS.

You can add the following CSS to your span so you will be able to change its width.

```
display: block;
```

Another way, which usually makes more sense, is to use a `<p>` element as a parent for your `<span>`.

```
<li id="CN2787">
  <img class="fav_star" src="images/fav.png">
  <p>
     <span>Text, text and more text</span>
  </p>
</li>
```

Since `<p>` is a `block` element, you can set its width using CSS, without having to change anything.

But in both cases, since you have a block element now, you will need to float the image so that your text doesn't all go below your image.

```
li p{width: 100px; margin-left: 20px}
.fav_star {width: 20px;float:left}
```

P.S. Instead of `float:left` on the image, you can also put `float:right` on `li p` but in that case, you will also need `text-align:left` to realign the text correctly.

P.S.S. If you went ahead with the first solution of not adding a `<p>` element, your CSS should look like so:

```
li span{width: 100px; margin-left: 20px;display:block}
.fav_star {width: 20px;float:left}
```

Comment: This is really helpful. I changed the `span` to a `p` element. Then just these two seemed to do the trick: `li p {margin-left: 40px} .fav_star {float: left}`. The width for the image is set by the image itself, the `p` element is automatically a `block` and I left the width alone. Thanks for this.

Comment: If you're going to use `display:block` you might just as well use a `div` since that's what it's for (or use a `p` as you also suggest). There's no need to double wrap the text - if you're using a `p` you can lose the `span`.

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't use HTML to change the design of your pages. This is the job for CSS (There are exception of course, specially when you need cross-browser compatibility). I believe that using proper HTML, and having "good semantics", is more important. So I wouldn't use a `div`, in this case, a `p` makes more sense. Losing the `span` is kinda trivial to me, and depends on how you are laying out your content.

Comment: Wrapping a `<span>` in a `<p>` is witchcraft straight out of Hogwartz! Works beautifully!

Answer (score 267):

Very simple answer for this problem that seems to catch a lot of people:

```
<img src="url-to-image">
<p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

    img {
        float: left;
    }
    p {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/vandigroup/upKGe/132/

Comment: This is the right answer to this question. This technique does not require to set a fixed width to the paragraph. Much simpler and easier solution. Works perfectly, even in IE8.

Comment: Well, in fact this won't work if the element containing the text were a `span` (the OP's case). A `display: block` would be needed for the `span`. But, saving that, I agree it's a much more elegant solution. In case anyone wonders what's the magic behind `overflow: hidden`, see my answer below.

Comment: Just for the record, this code solves some problems with Twitter Bootstrap 3 navbars with images and text.  The text wrapped for no reason.

Comment: Caveot: `overflow: hidden;` trick only works on `display: block;` elements, which `<p>` is by default, but if you try it with a `<span>` it won't work unless you chagne the display style. Very strange that this works... I'd love some explanation of why this is the "correct" behavior.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike The reason why is that `<p>` is a block level element and a span is an inline element (designed to work within block level elements). This is the same reason why you cannot add margin or padding, for example, to a span. Once you add the `display` attribute you can use these block level attributes. Also, I use `display: inline-block` on spans more than `display: block`.

Comment: @JoeConlin - Sorry, re-reading my own comment, I can see how that was unclear; I understand that `overflow` only works on block elements. What I meant was that it isn't really clear from the CSS spec that overflow would cause it to not wrap around a float. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow-clipping and https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3 It isn't really specifically mentioned. It's just one of those interesting CSS behaviors that few people seem to know about.

Comment: Can someone explain how this works? This is unbelievable, but not the behavior I would expect if I came across this in a css file.

Answer (score 28):

For those who want some background info, here's a [short article](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/) explaining why `overflow: hidden` works. It has to do with the so-called **block formatting context**. This is part of W3C's spec (ie is not a hack) and is basically the region occupied by an element with a block-type flow.

Every time it is applied, `overflow: hidden` creates a *new* block formatting context. But it's not the only property capable of triggering that behaviour. Quoting a [presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YtQwv1cUVs) by Fiona Chan from Sydney Web Apps Group:

> - float: left / right
> - overflow: hidden / auto / scroll
> - display: table-cell and any table-related values / inline-block
> - position: absolute / fixed

Comment: Can you add some details from that article into your answer, in case the link goes dead?

Comment: Good morning Australia! Thanks for the comment.

Comment: This is excellent for displaying code blocks that might have to contend with images or floating sidebars nearby.

Comment: The technique as originally described works well, though as others have said, it's not behavior I would expect. However, I don't see that float or inline-block work without overflow, and of course table-related display values and position absolute or fixed have other layout consequences that may or may not be acceptable in context.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the `margin-left` to work on a `span` element you'll need to make it `display: inline-block` or `display:block` as well.

Comment: Probably need `vertical-align: top;` on the image with this, as well.

Answer (score 2):

setting `display:flex`for the text worked for me.

Comment: This seems to be a more modern equivalent of setting `overflow:auto`. I'm sure it doesn't work exactly the same in all situations, but it worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a div around the image and the span and add the following to CSS like so:

HTML

```
        <li id="CN2787">
          <div><img class="fav_star" src="images/fav.png"></div>
          <div><span>Text, text and more text</span></div>
        </li>
```

CSS

```
            #CN2787 > div { 
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
            }

            #CN2787 > div:first-of-type {
                width: 35%;
            }

            #CN2787 > div:last-of-type {
                width: 65%;
            }
```

LESS

```
        #CN2787 {
            > div { 
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
            }

            > div:first-of-type {
                width: 35%;
            }
            > div:last-of-type {
                width: 65%;
            }
        }
```