# Aligning image and text in an unordered list using Bootstrap framework

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Quite a particular problem I am trying to solve right now and it does not really particularly seem to fit other questions I have looked up. What I have got is a project using a modified Bootstrap css framework and on a particular page we have partner logos within an unordered list with the image and text title wrapped by an anchor tag, here is a link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/coolwebs/ygpu3sja/1/

I have found a good post on SO here [CSS to stop text wrapping under image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411219/css-to-stop-text-wrapping-under-image) which helped me stop having the text wrap around the bottom of the image by floating the img left. However the partner title text is now all top aligned next to each logo. I want to have the text vertically aligned in the middle instead of starting at the top. Is there any way to achieve this? As soon as I float the image to the left, the text aligns to the top of all the images.

I am hoping that I am missing some minor css here.

Here is the code if it helps:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="entry-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <h2>Partners</h2>
            <ul class="icons-listing">
                <li><a href="https://www.education.gov.au/national-collaborative-research-infrastructure-strategy-ncris"
                       target="_blank"> <img
                        src="https://research.qut.edu.au/biorefining/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2017/03/ncris.png"
                        alt=""><span class="partner-text">An Australian Government Initiative National Collaborative Research Infrastructure
                    Strategy</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.mackaysugar.com.au/Pages/default.aspx" target="_blank"> <img
                        src="https://research.qut.edu.au/biorefining/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2017/03/mackay-sugar.png"
                        alt="">Mackay Sugar</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.qld.gov.au/" target="_blank"> <img
                        src="https://research.qut.edu.au/biorefining/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2017/03/queensland-government.png"
                        alt="">Queensland Government</a></li>
            </ul>


</div>
</div>

.icons-listing {
    list-style: none;
}

.content .icons-listing li {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.content .icons-listing img {
  float: left;
}

.partner-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.icons-listing {
    list-style: none;
}

.content .icons-listing li {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.content .icons-listing img {
  float: left;
}

.partner-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: none;
}
li a {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="entry-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <h2>Partners</h2>
            <ul class="icons-listing">
                <li><a href="https://www.education.gov.au/national-collaborative-research-infrastructure-strategy-ncris"
                       target="_blank"> <img
                        src="https://research.qut.edu.au/biorefining/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2017/03/ncris.png"
                        alt=""><span class="partner-text">An Australian Government Initiative National Collaborative Research Infrastructure
                    Strategy</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.mackaysugar.com.au/Pages/default.aspx" target="_blank"> <img
                        src="https://research.qut.edu.au/biorefining/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2017/03/mackay-sugar.png"
                        alt="">Mackay Sugar</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.qld.gov.au/" target="_blank"> <img
                        src="https://research.qut.edu.au/biorefining/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2017/03/queensland-government.png"
                        alt="">Queensland Government</a></li>
            </ul>


</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/ygpu3sja/2/)

Comment: Good ol' FLEX... Simple and effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to make the anchor to display as table and nested imaga tag and span tag as display:table-cell

below is the codepen link..

i think this is what u want to get...

```
[Here is the codepen link][1]
  [1]: https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/jwNEQz?editors=1100
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's good much other responder's suggestion was simpler.